# test an http call inside a promise with jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am learning angular and unit testing and can't seem to get past this issue. Perhaps I am doing it all wrong but i want to test that an http call was made.

app.service.ts:

```
transformData(data):Promise<any>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.post<any>('https://www.example.com',data).subscribe(
        resp => {
         resolve(resp);
         },
        err => {
         reject(err);
         }
      );

       });
    }
```

my test is now:

```
fit("should submit data for processing", fakeAsync(() => {

    const service = TestBed.get(AppService);

    let response = {
      processedData: 100
    };

    service
    .transformData({'data':'data'})
    .then(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual(response);
    });

   // Expect a call to this URL
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(
  "https://www.example.com/"
    );
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual("POST");
  req.flush(response);
  tick();

  }));
```

It says:

```
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://www.example.com/", found none.
```

Comment: Why are you doing that to start with? Use the observable, or if you really must have promises use the observable's `.toPromise()` method.

Comment: I think you have a leading slash in your URL, try changing `const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(
  "https://www.example.com/"
    );` to `const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(
  "https://www.example.com"
    );`

Comment: @jonrsharpe toPromise(), good spot thank you. But still I can't seem to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I would test it like so:

```
fit("should submit data for processing", async(done) => {

    const service = TestBed.get(AppService);

    let response = {
      processedData: 100
    };

    service
    .transformData({'data':'data'})
    .then(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual(response);
      // call done() to tell the test we are done with our assertions
      done();
    });

    // Expect a call to this URL
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne("https://www.example.com");
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("POST");
    req.flush(response);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @AliF50. I tried that. While the test won't fail, it is not right

Comment: Why is it not right? You can have your own assertions.

Comment: i take back my comment, sorry. I wasn't running the test when i said it wasn't failing. Now I run it, it just timesout, i assume due to the async nature of the http calls, which I faced at first when i tried with done=> (without async). Thanks still and I apolgise.